# Data is not saving to the database but shows on terminal in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

So i have been trying to add Tags using django-taggit, but for some reason tags are not saving to the database when i try to upload a post using website but it works perfectly with django admin(Tags are saving to the database).

Also when i go to my Post_edit view and try to update empty tags field then it works.
In other words, tags are only saving to the database when i try to edit it using Postedit view or upload it using admin. I want it to save to the database using PostUpload view only(like i have to use PostEdit view for every post to display tags).
I think there's something wrong either with my view or form.

Also i can see request.POST data is returning the list of Tags on the terminal and form returns no errors.

Everything else is saving to the database except Tags.

here's my code

**Views.py**

## Uploading Posts( views.py )

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def post_upload(request):
    index1 = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-time')[0]
    content = request.POST.get('content')
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    image = request.FILES.get('image')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostUpload(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            tags = post_form.cleaned_data['tags']
            context = post_form.cleaned_data['context']
            excerpt_type = post_form.cleaned_data['excerpt_type']
            ins = Blog.objects.create(user=request.user, content=content, title=title, image=image, context=context,
                                      tags=tags, excerpt_type=excerpt_type)
            ins.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your Post has been successfully posted')
            print(request.POST)
            print(tags)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_upload'))
        else:
            print(f'error in {request.POST}')
    else:
        post_form = PostUpload(instance=request.user)
    context = {'post_form': post_form, 'index1': index1}
    return render(request, 'post_upload.html', context)
```

## For editing Posts( views.py )

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def post_edit(request, pk):
    index1 = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-time')[0]
    post = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=pk)
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edit_form = PostEdit(request.POST or None, request.FILES, instance=post)
        if edit_form.is_valid():
            edit_form.save()
            print(request.POST)
            messages.success(request, 'Your Post has been updated successfully')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        edit_form = PostEdit(instance=post)
    context = {'edit_form': edit_form, 'post': post, 'user': user, 'index1': index1}
    return render(request, 'post_edit.html', context)
```

## models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, default="/static/img/900x300.png")
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, unique_with='title')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    excerpt_type = models.ForeignKey(Excerpt, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    context = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    @property
    def image_url(self):
        if self.image and hasattr(self.image, 'url'):
            return self.image.url
        else:
            return "/static/images/900x300.png"

    @property
    def get_month_name(self):
        if self.time.month == 1:
            return 'January'
        elif self.time.month == 2:
            return 'February'
        elif self.time.month == 3:
            return 'March'
        elif self.time.month == 4:
            return 'April'
        elif self.time.month == 5:
            return 'May'
        elif self.time.month == 6:
            return 'June'
        elif self.time.month == 7:
            return 'July'
        elif self.time.month == 8:
            return 'August'
        elif self.time.month == 9:
            return 'September'
        elif self.time.month == 10:
            return 'October'
        elif self.time.month == 10:
            return 'November'
        elif self.time.month == 12:
            return 'December'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' by ' + self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:posts", args=[str(self.slug)])
```

## forms.py

```
class PostUpload(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog

        exclude = ['slug', 'user', 'views']


class PostEdit(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog

        exclude = ['slug', 'user', 'views']
```

## blogposts.html

```
 {% if tag %}
                        <div class="sidebar-box ftco-animate">
                            <h3>Tag Cloud</h3>
                            <div class="tagcloud">
                                {% for tag in Blog.tags.all %}
                                    <a href="{% url 'tagged' tag.slug %}" class="tag-cloud-link">{{ tag }}</a>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
```

## post_upload.html

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container rounded bg-white mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="col-md-8 mt-3">
    <form class="form-group" action="./" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
    {% csrf_token %}

                    <label for="validationDefaultUsername">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefaultUsername"
                               value="{{ user.username }}" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" disabled>
                    </div>

        {{ post_form.errors | as_crispy_errors }}
        {{ post_form.media }}
        {{ post_form | crispy }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="btn" style="color: blueviolet;">
</form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

## post_edit.html

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container rounded bg-white mt-5 mb-5">
        <div class="col-md-8 mt-3 mb-3">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-group">


                {% csrf_token %}

                    <label for="validationDefaultUsername">Username</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroupPrepend2">@</span>
                        </div>
                        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="validationDefaultUsername"
                               value="{{ user.username }}" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend2" disabled>
                    </div>

                {{ edit_form.errors }}
                {{ edit_form.media }}
                {{ edit_form | crispy }}
                <input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="btn" style="color: blueviolet;">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to save the object first then split the tag values by comma and then add the tags into the field of your object this way. I have added the comments for your understanding.
**Views.py
Uploading Posts( views.py )**

```py
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def post_upload(request):
    index1 = Blog.objects.all().order_by('-time')[0]
    content = request.POST.get('content')
    title = request.POST.get('title')
    image = request.FILES.get('image')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostUpload(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if post_form.is_valid():
            tags = post_form.cleaned_data['tags']
            context = post_form.cleaned_data['context']
            excerpt_type = post_form.cleaned_data['excerpt_type']
            # Removed tags=tags from the below line
            # Also, if you want to use `save` then you don't want to use
            # `create` as it will persist into your db right away.
            # Simply create an instance of Blog
            ins = Blog(user=request.user, content=content, title=title,
                        image=image, context=context,
                        excerpt_type=excerpt_type)
                # Adding tags against the object field after the object creation
            for tag in tags:
                ins.tags.add(tag)
            ins.save()
            
            messages.success(request, 'Your Post has been successfully posted')
            print(request.POST)
            print(tags)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_upload'))
        else:
            print(f'error in {request.POST}')
    else:
        post_form = PostUpload(instance=request.user)
    context = {'post_form': post_form, 'index1': index1}
    return render(request, 'post_upload.html', context)
```

Comment: just change this line 
tags = post_form.cleaned_data['tags']

to this line 
tags = request.POST.get('tags', False)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call **form.save_m2m()** to save tags when using django-taggit library like this:

```
    post_form = PostUpload(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
    if post_form.is_valid():
        obj = post_form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save()
        # Without this next line the tags won't be saved.
        post_form.save_m2m()
        messages.success(request, 'Your Post has been successfully posted')
        print(request.POST)
        print(tags)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_upload'))
```

You can read more [here](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#commit-false).

Answer (score 0):

Inside `post_upload` method, are you sure you need `instance=request.user` to create a `post_form` object?